# Htaccess .Redirec double slash containing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I  have a site called mydomain.com . I am crating 'sites' folder in it where  I will be creating many sites for my users . I want for example for a user 'Jack' create a folder called 'jack' so now they can access their page via mydomain.com/sites/jack . 
 So my question is how to make my users go mydomain.com/jack  but still see the content of the above url and also make 'mydomain.com/sites/jack'  sorts of urls  forbidden .
Thanks very much for your time !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check to see if this user's site exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites%{REQUEST_URI} -d

# Rewrite into the /sites/ directory
RewriteRule !^/?sites/ /sites%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


# Redirect requests made directly to /sites/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /sites/
RewriteRule ^/?sites/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you are a life saver thanks sooo much . I into a project and dont have time to learn these helpful things but I hope I will always come across kind people like you to help me with htaccess . Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: Jon but main directory in this case mydomain.com isnt recognizing the index.php file and show folders in main domain. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @user1485518 Try adding this right after `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+` to ensure that the request isn't blank